# Skewness for a sum of independent weighted bernoulli random variables with different probabilities of success

Tags: distributions, independence, skewness, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Suppose $Z_i$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with differing probabilities $P_i$. Also suppose weights $W_i$ are positive and constant. Let's define the random variable $S$ which is the summation of each weighted $Z_i$ (i.e. $S=\sum_i W_iZ_i$).

The Poisson binomial distribution is a special case for this distribution, where $W_i=1$ for all $i$.

Does anyone have any idea of how to compute the skewness for the distribution of the random variable $S$?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward (by the look of it a [routine bookwork-style question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)). Is this for some class? (If not, how does it arise?)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're [aware of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) basic properties of expectation:

1. $E(X+Y) = E(X)+E(Y)$

   (the generalizations of these to $n$ variables is obvious by repeated application of the case with two terms)
2. $E(cX) = cE(X)$

   I assume you're also [aware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) that for independent random variables
3. $\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)$

   and (for any random variable whose variance exists)
4. $\text{Var}(cX) = c^2\text{Var}(X)$

   What you might not have seen is the extension to [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Uses_in_statistics) (also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29#Cumulants)) of higher order than 2, which gives us (for independent random variables):
5. $\mu_k(X+Y) = \mu_k(X)+\mu_k(Y)$

   Further, I assume it is immediately clear that
6. $\mu_k(cX) = c^k\mu_k(X)$

   -- but if it is not, it should be easy for you to prove by elementary means.

These tools (specifically 3-6 or even just 5&6) should be sufficient to obtain the result you need in a couple of lines.