# Moments of an AR(1) Process

Tags: autoregressive, moments, cumulants

### Definition of an AR(1) process

In an [Autoregressive Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), a time series can be generated based on a stochastic difference equation.

\begin{align}
X_t = c + \phi \, X_{t-1} + \epsilon
\end{align}

Typically, $\epsilon$ is chosen to be *normally distributed* and $0 < \phi < 1$.

### What I already know

As described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Example:_An_AR(1)_process), as well as on [Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/prove-expression-for-variance-ar1), one can derive the *mean* and the *variance* of the resulting time series if one knows the parameters $c$ and $\phi$, as well as the distribution of $\epsilon$.

\begin{align}
Mean(X_t) & = Mean(c + \phi \, X_{t-1} + \epsilon) \\
& = Mean(c) + Mean(\phi \, X_{t-1}) + Mean(\epsilon) \\
& = c + \phi \, Mean(X_{t-1}) + 0 \\
\end{align}

Assuming that $Mean(X_{t}) = Mean(X_{t-1})$, it follows that:

\begin{align}
Mean(X_t) = \frac{c}{1 - \phi}
\end{align}

Similarly for the *variance*:

\begin{align}
Var(X_t) & = Var(c + \phi \, X_{t-1} + \epsilon) \\
& = Var(c) + Var(\phi \, X_{t-1}) + Var(\epsilon) \\
& = 0 + \phi^2 \, Var(X_{t-1}) + \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \\
\end{align}

Assuming that $Var(X_{t}) = Var(X_{t-1})$, it follows that:

\begin{align}
Var(X_t) = \frac{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2}{1 - \phi^2}
\end{align}

### My question

How can this be generalised to higher order *moments*, *central moments* and/or *cumulants*?

Following [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214041/skewness-for-a-sum-of-independent-weighted-bernoulli-random-variables-with-diffe) post, is it correct to assume that:

\begin{align}
\mu_k(X_t) = \frac{\mu_k(\epsilon)}{1 - \phi^k}
\end{align}

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Example:_An_AR(1)_process), it is noted that:

> ...the central limit theorem indicates that $X_t$ will be approximately normally distributed when $\phi$ is close to one.

Which makes me doubt whether the above generalisation is correct.

Secondly, $\mu_k$ refers to *cumulants*. Is there a similar expression for *moments* and/or *central moments*?

### Context

I would like to end up with an *AR(1)* process which generates data with a particular non-normal distribution. I want to be able to specify the desired *mean*, *standard deviation* and *skewness* and subsequently work back what distribution I need for $\epsilon$ to give me the expected result.

Comment: The AR(1) process with normal noise is a discrete-time version of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Markov process, which has as stationary distribution the Gaussian distribution. If you replace $X_{t-1}$ with the log-gradient of your non-normal distribution, you will approximately draw samples from that distribution.

Comment: @Forgottenscience What do you mean with 'log-gradient'?

Comment: Say your distribution of interest is $p(x)$, then the derivative of $\log p(x)$ with respect to $x$ would be the log-derivative; if $x$ was a vector it would be the log-gradient. See for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis-adjusted_Langevin_algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formulas for $\mbox{Var}X_t$ and the higher order cumulants $\mu_k(X_t)$ are both correct but note that the skewness of $X_t$ (the third standardised moment) is
$$
\mbox{Skew}X_t = \frac{\mu_3(X_t)}{\mu_2(X_t)^{3/2}}=\frac{\mu_3(\epsilon_t)(1-\phi^2)^{3/2}}{\mbox{Var}(\epsilon_t)^{3/2}(1-\phi^3)}=\mbox{Skew}(\epsilon_t)\frac{(1-\phi^2)^{3/2}}{(1-\phi^3)}
$$
In contrast to $\mu_3(X_t)$ this goes to zero as expected from the central limit theorem as $\phi$ goes to 1 no matter how skewed the white noise is.

Comment: Interesting. So adjusting the distribution of $X_t$ is not possible by adjusting the distribution of $\epsilon$ as it will always tend to the normal distribution? What other strategies are there to obtain a non-normal distribution for $X_t$?

Comment: No, as long as $\phi<1$ you are not in this limiting case, so you can get any skew you want in $X_t$ since there is no upper bound on the skew of $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: True, but for $\phi \approx 1$, it would require quite extreme values of $\epsilon$ to achieve the desired distribution of $X_t$. Perhaps it is easier (more stable?) to use a transformation $f$ on $X$ such that $f(X_t)$ is normally distributed. (Or would these end up mathematically equivalent to each other? Thinking out loud here...)

Comment: But for non-linear $f$ the autocovariance function of the transformed process $Y_t=f(X_t)$ would not have exponential decay so $Y_t$ would not be AR(1).

Comment: So you're saying that non-linearly transforming an $AR(1)$ process yields (in general) an $AR(\infty)$. That might be something I am willing to accept. Do you (or anyone else) know of alternative methods of getting a mean-reverting Markov time series with a non-normal distribution?

Comment: This seems related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180109/generate-a-random-variable-which-follow-gamma-distribution-and-ar1-process-sim

Comment: Also note that cumulants are identical to central moments only up for order 3 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_and_moments). The expression above can be generalised easily for central moments, but requires additional terms for cumulants.

Comment: @JarleTufto - could these results be applied to find the cumulants of a general ARMA(p,q) process ?  If so, how?